# find which event is triggred in backbone js event callback function

Tags: backbone.js

```
obj.on('evt_A evt_B evt_c', function(eventData){
console.log("Is it possible here to find which event is triggered. As this callback is registered for three events. This callback is like a central callback for all the events on this object.")
})

obj.trigger('evt_A evt_B evt_c', [{eventDataForevt_A}, {eventDataForevt_B, {eventDataForevt_C}}])
```

There is one way of doing it, which is having a property in `eventDataForevt_<A||B||C>` which says the name of the event. But is it possible to do this without modifying the `eventDataForevt_<A||B||C>` ?

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(eventData)`? Any reference to the name of the calling event?

Comment: Do you have a concrete example I can work through here? I'm struggling to imagine how your events are actually firing. Are evt_A..C attributes of `obj` that you're watching for changes?

Comment: Wait, got it. Posting answer

Comment: `'evt_A evt_B evt_c' are not attributes of the `obj`, but they are custom event names on `obj`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To Find Triggered Event From Backbone.listenTo?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248801/how-to-find-triggered-event-from-backbone-listento)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this fiddle: http://jsbin.com/ucevov/4/edit

It doesn't seem possible to detect the event name from your `obj.on` - note that `evt_c in this._events` is `true` even when `evt_c` is not called.

However there is [a special "all" event](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) which passes in the name of the calling event as the first parameter, so

```
obj.on("all", function(eventName, eventData) {
  console.log(eventName);
});
```

should output the name of the event that was called.